# C++11, integer-type determined by range?

Tags: c++11, long-integer, numeric-limits

So this question came up, while doing rather some simple coding, consider the following;

```
for(unsigned int x=0x00000000; x<0xFFFFFFFF; x++)
{
    // ...
}
```

The above code, works as expected assuming 'sizeof(unsigned int) >= 4', however as we know, on some platforms this may not be true, hence I'm interrested in something alike this;

```
for(RangeBasedInt<0x00000000, 0xFFFFFFFF>::type x=0x00000000; x<0xFFFFFFFF; x++)
{
    // ...
}
```

Where 'RangeInt' is a template, with 'type' being the smallest integer type large enough to hold the range of values from MINIMUM (0x00000000) to MAXIMUM (0xFFFFFFFF);

```
template<int MINIMUM, int MAXIMUM>
struct RangeBasedInt
{
    // Type based upon MINIMUM and MAXIMUM
    typedef /* MAGIC */ type;
};
```

So the question, in it's simplicity is;

1. Is this implemented somewhere in the standard library?
2. If not, is there a library implementing this, or will I have to build my own based upon std::numeric_limits

Answer (score 2):

It is really easy to implement this yourself.  So easy I'd say it is implemented in the language:

```
typedef decltype(0xFFFFFFFF) RangeBasedInt;
for(RangeBasedInt x=0x00000000; x<0xFFFFFFFF; x++)
{
    // ...
}
```

2.14.2 [lex.icon] states that the type of an integral literal is the smallest type that can hold the value.  So if `int` can hold `0xFFFFFFFF` on your machine, `RangeBasedInt` could be an `int`.  On my machine, it is `unsigned int`.

For this particular limit (`0xFFFFFFFF`), the standard guarantees that it can be represented by one of the built-in integral types.  `ULONG_MAX` must be no less than 4294967295 (0xFFFFFFFF), and `ULLONG_MAX` must be no less than 18446744073709551615 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF).

**Update**

I stand corrected by Skeen on a technicality.  Table 6 in [lex.icon] doesn't actually say "smallest type".  It actually says that if the literal is an octal or hexadecimal constant that it will be the first type in the following list in which its value can be represented:

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

The table goes on it specify different lists depending on whether the literal is a decimal, or not, and whether it is suffixed or not.  I was definitely paraphrasing when I said "smallest".  For the precise details please consult the actual standard, and not a SO answer (by me or anyone else).  As I write this, the latest draft of C++1y is [N3691](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf).

Comment: What if the lower limit is (or both are) negative, how would you deal with that?

Comment: Then your implementation of `RangeBasedInt` gets more complicated. :-)  However it only gets as complicated as you want to make it.  If you have a limit expressed as a negative number, you can still `decltype` that literal (assuming it is a literal) and get a signed integral type which will represent it.  If you want to make a truly general `RangeBasedInt<Min, Max>`, you can do that.  It does not exist in the standard library.  And decltype will help a lot.

Comment: I do not believe 2.14.2, states what you're saying, correct me with a reference, if I'm wrong. Both GCC and Clang seem to generate int for the limits (0x0, 0xFF), where unsigned char would be the smallest type. (could be compiler imperfection)

Comment: 2.14.2 states that; "The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 6 in which its value can be represented." - Without any suffixes the sequence is; "int, long int, long long int".

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your comment, and included a handy link to an actual draft C++1y.

Comment: @Skeen: There are no negative integer literals.  `-42` is an expression consisting of the literal `42` with the unary minus `operator-` applied to it.  Literals are defined in clause 2, but the unary minus operator is defined in clause 5.